# How to respond to comment on suggested documentation change

Tags: support, documentation

I received a comment on a documentation change that I had suggested. I couldn't find any way to respond to the comment.

Fortunately, I found more to edit within the topic, and resubmitted the documentation change suggestion. I made sure to address the comment in the new edit summary.

Is responding to comments on suggested documentation changes supported somehow in Documentation?

Comment: You can add another comment (although this appears to be temperamental - errors - and doesn't always work - try several times)

Comment: @DavidPostill I can't even see a UI element to add comments. Maybe I don't have the privilege.

Comment: If you click on your proposed change you should see all the comments at the end ...

Comment: Click on the comment notification in your inbox. What do you see? Can you share that link?

Comment: @DavidPostill only available until you retract the edit maybe?

Comment: @DavidPostill http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/80864?draftId=67651#commentId=14480

Comment: Yeah, I suppose retraction would remove the comments. You should have a "comment" discussion and **then** retract if agreed ...

Comment: Here's one of mine that hasn't been retracted https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/78778?draftId=43678#commentId=13944 - still awaiting approval

Comment: @DavidPostill I can see the "add a comment" link on yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is responding to comments on suggested documentation changes supported somehow in Documentation?

Yes, but ...

- Adding new comments is supported as long as the status of the edit is **Status: Awaiting approval**.
- If you retract the edit (**Status: Retracted**) then you are no longer able to add comments. Existing comments on the proposed edit remain visible.

Comment: I can still see existing comments on my edit suggestions.

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga On the retracted ones?

Comment: Yep. I never had a chance to make my own comments, so mine are not there, but other users' comments remain.

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga Thanks. Answer updated.